# Allow only hex numbers c# WP8.1

Tags: c#

Im trying block any number that dont be hex number, using Virtualkey and your codes

```
 private void TxthexSoma1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Key == (VirtualKey)(65) ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(66) ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(67) ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(68) ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(69) ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(70) ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(48) ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(49) ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(50) ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(51) ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(52) ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(53) ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(54) ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(55) ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(56) ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(57) ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(20) ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(8)  ||
            e.Key == (VirtualKey)(46))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

But have some problems, for example: if the first lyric is uppercase happen nothing, and others characters  like : (, ), #, ! and many others are accepets

how fixed this ?

Comment: I believe you want to put `0x` in front of all those numbers so you get the hex value instead of the decimal value.

Comment: Try `e.KeyChar` and compare it to the characters (`0`, `1`, `2`, etc.) that way.

Comment: juharr, I want only numbers hex(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F), the way that I use work, but if the first  lyric is uppercase dont happen nothing. Dont working this way EBrown